# Reverse a division

Tags: divisibility

I'm working on a program and I'm starting to regret the way I've done this. I start with a user selected number between 0.2 and 24 (lets call it *a*) then divide 12 by that number (so 12/*a* = *b*). Is there a way I can get *a* from the result, *b*?

I know that if you knew *a*, you could do *a* * *b* = 12 though that's not an option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{12}{a}=b$

$12=ab$

$\frac{12}{b}=a$